# Website OK button doesn't work

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, button, reporting-services, submit

<sub>**Note:** answering my own question to save others from the hair pulling frustration!</sub>

After installing SQL Reporting Server and browsing to the Site Settings to add roles **the OK button didn't work**. Its like the OK button isn't wired up!

[image]

Obviously I searched the internet for a solution:

a) https://ask.sqlservercentral.com/questions/1842/ssrs-acting-stranglyok-button-doesnt-work.html

> "OK buttons didn't work because of the security settings of IE. I tried it on another server is IE 7 and it worked fine. So the problem was with IE 8 and high security settings"

b) https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/sqlserver/en-US/523cab0c-1019-4360-90a7-f12aac657a23/sql-2005-ssrs-web-page-ok-or-apply-button-not-working

> "This error might be caused by a couple of things.
>
> 1. The account which you use to logon the report manager don't have enough permission to upload the files. Try to assign "Content Manager” role your account.
> 2. The account which you use to logon the report manager don't have enough permission on report server database. Try to assign "RSExecRole" role to the user account in report server database"

c) http://community.dynamics.com/ax/f/33/p/170669/422185

> "clear the cache"

Answer (score 0):

*No solutions on the internet worked. I added Accounts to SSRS Database, loosened the web browser security settings, tried different browsers basically every thing short of hitting it with a hammer!*

---

So I ended up debugging the problem myself. By viewing the HTML source I saw the OK button called some javascript validation:

```
<input name="ui_btnSave" type="button" id="ui_btnSave" 
style="width:;" class="msrs-button" value="OK" language="Javascript"         
onclick="if(typeof(Page_ClientValidate)=='function')   
if(Page_ClientValidate()) if(true) __doPostBack('ctl173','');" />
```

How annoying I thought, this javascript validation doesn't show any messages, if just fails silently!!!

**onclick="if(typeof(Page_ClientValidate)=='function')

    if(Page_ClientValidate()) if(true) __doPostBack('ctl173','');"**

So I decided to ignore the validation and trigger the __doPostBack function.

> **Solution:** To trigger a javascript function on a page without clicking a button you just type this in the address bar (where functionName is the name of the javascript method):

```
javascript:functionName
```

[image]

And hey presto the new role was added! What the validation does I don't really care, it probably would have told me that Active Scripting is disabled or something silly!